# Права администратора для приложения

Tags: python, администрирование, exe, права

мне нужно чтобы при запуске программы запрашивались права администратора у пользователя. Как это сделать?Приложение написано на Python и скомпилировано в exe

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы за вас написали?

Comment: Линукс или виндовс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого в вашу сборку необходимо добавить файл манифеста с прописанными параметрами для UAC. Манифест - это обычный xml файл, который определяет требования и привилегии приложения.
Это может выглядеть так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" />
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```